# Count PDF nodes using ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I've already used ghostscript to check PDF files and now i need to identify a pdf with more than 1000 nodes. Is it possible to use ghostscript to count the number of nodes a PDF have?

My knowledge with ghostscript is basic and I have difficulty finding a solution in ruby (PDF reader 1.3) or using tools like imageMagick.

Edit:
I can not explain in a more technical way what kind of node I'm looking for. These nodes are equivalent to those found in the corel draw. Initially I thought it would not have equivalent in pdf however the pitstop plugin has the functionality to indentify nodes.

[Example of identified nodes by PitStop Pro](https://ibb.co/eW7RHw)

Comment: What do you mean by 'nodes' ? There are several different kinds of tree potentially present in a PDF file, and each of them can have nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't 'nodes', they are the start and end points of path segments. Ghostscript doesn't have a device to extract paths. It could do so easily enough (and recover the curve control points which don't appear to be displayed in your PitStop screen grab).

However, Ghostscript isn't an editing tool, so its not at all clear what you would intend to do with the information.

If you want this, then you are going to have to either parse the PDF yourself, or write a Ghostscript device to retrieve the information, or write a program for some other tool (eg MuPDF) to extract path information.